# Variance using Gaussian distribution Python

Tags: python, random, gaussian

I have a code which calculates the square of a number using Gaussian distribution in python. Now my task is to calculate the variance for the same. But when I try, i keep getting error. The code is as follows:

```
import random
def generate_data(size):
    n = 5
    m =0.5
    mu, sigma = n ** 2, m/3
    return [random.gauss(mu, sigma) for _ in range(size)]


def average(ls):
    avg =  sum(ls) / len(ls)
    variance = (sum(ls) - sum(avg)) ** 2 / len(ls)

    return variance
```

I am not good in statistics, so I might be wrong with the formula too. and I am also a beginner in python.The error I get is

```
'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your formula for variance is wrong

Comment: could u pls help me in fixing it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the full error traceback.

Comment: I think you call your function with only one value. On a side note: why don't you use `numpy.mean()` and `numpy.std()`?

Comment: You can't take `sum(avg)` since `avg` is a float. You probably meant `sum(ls) -  avg * len(ls))` or something like that

Comment: @Faultier: numpy helped. thank u :)

Comment: but out of curiosity. If i have to do it by formula, how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variance formula should be

```
variance = sum(map(lambda x: (x-avg) ** 2, ls)) / len(ls)
```

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable)

Since `variance = sigma^2` you can test your code by printing `math.sqrt(variance)`

```
import random, math


def generate_data(size):
    n = 5
    m = 0.5
    mu, sigma = n ** 2, m/3
    return [random.gauss(mu, sigma) for _ in range(size)]


def variance(ls):
    avg = sum(ls) / len(ls)
    variance = sum(map(lambda x: (x-avg) ** 2, ls)) / len(ls)

    return variance

print(0.5/3)                                     #0.16666666666666666
print(math.sqrt(variance(generate_data(100))))   #0.15702629417476763
print(math.sqrt(variance(generate_data(1000))))  #0.16248850600497303
print(math.sqrt(variance(generate_data(10000)))) #0.16774494705918871
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find that doing mean,variance in one go, might be faster than 3 passes approach (sum + map + sum)

```
def average(ls):
    sum  = 0.0
    sum2 = 0.0
    for v in ls:
        sum  += v
        sum2 += v*v

    mean = sum / len(ls)
    var  = sum2/len(ls) - mean*mean

    return (mean, var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want or have to do it yourself I would use `numpy`.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html